# Is repartitioning before writing a delta table pointless if you perform z-ordering right after?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, partitioning, delta-lake

Is it correct to say that calling `repartition` or `partitionByRange` on a Spark DataFrame does not make sense if you intend to perform Delta table optimize with z-order right after? Since it will likely change the order of rows and compact the stored files anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably yes, it's not required - as the order of the rows will be changed anyway by OPTIMIZE. Also, you may consider disabling [optimized write](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/tune-file-size.html#optimized-writes) if you will do OPTIMIZE right after the write.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Never seen that page before. If you don't mind me asking more questions: 1) would you recommend auto optimized writes for batch jobs that only append more data partitioned by date each run (with rare occasional rewrites) over running optimize with z-order manually? 2) would you recommend tuning target file size manually, or just leave it to the default settings? I'm not sure when it would make sense to do that.

Comment: Please note that optimized write just creates fewer big files, while OPTIMIZE will also perform data collocation (ZOrder). Target file size is usually tuned when you use merge/update/delete, but with introduction of predictive I/O (aka deletion vectors) the need for it is smaller. In general the decision about optimized write vs. explicit OPTIMIZE heavily dependent on the amount of data ingested & data reading patterns